# Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php

Всем, привет! Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. Делаю все правильно вот по этому [примеру](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/login-with-instagram-php.html). Когда вызываю **index.php** получаю вот это:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /var/www/u1682519/data/www/lelbrus.by/index.php:7) in /var/www/u1682519/data/www/lelbrus.by/index.php on line 35

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/u1682519/data/www/lelbrus.by/index.php:7) in /var/www/u1682519/data/www/lelbrus.by/index.php on line 38
```

Answer (score 1):

Но ведь вы ответили на свой невопрос в заголовке.
Если бы я был [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com)'ом, то мог бы сказать, что заголовки уже отправлены в файле index.php, строка 7.